# Где нужно проводить инициализацию Android приложения?

Tags: android

Где нужно проводить инициализацию Android приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `onCreate` класса, унаследованного от `Activity`.

Answer (score 2):

Также широко распространена практика выполнения инициализирующих действий в методе onStart(), например, в нем логично выполнять зачитывание настроек из shared preferences